# Can I use a visualforce page to create a link that copies fields from one place to another?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-button

I want to add a custom link on my Contacts Page Layout to allow users to copy Service Address to Mailing Address if they are the same. I'm trying to use Visualforce page to do this using onclick event?  Is this the right approach?

**Copy Service Address to Mailing Address**

Comment: Are you trying to build this from scratch, there are multiple ways to do this, I would recommend a ajax script for this than a VF route if you already have started the VF route please post what you have so that we can help you finsih it

Comment: Hello, I would prefer to not complicate things if there is an easier way. How would I go about adding the Ajax code to my page layout?

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to build the whole thing in VF just to support this functionality. The copy of service address to mailing address could be achieved by simply adding a checkbox and some WF field update.
You can create a WF rule that will copy the service address to mailing address when this checkbox is selected.

Comment: Hello, Thanks for replying. So would I be adding a Custom Checkbox on Contact. If so, what else would I have to do after adding the check box on page layout? Could you give me an example how to go about this? Thanks.

Comment: Once you have added this custom checkbox. Create a WF rule on contact. The evalutaion criteria should be "every time the record is created or edited". In the rule criteria check if the "custom checkbox" is set to true. As an action item create field updates for copying values into the address field.

Comment: Ok, I'm going to give is a shot right now.

Comment: Hello, I created the workflow but i'm getting the following error message. Error: Formula result is data type (Boolean), incompatible with expected data type (Text).

Comment: Also, it looks like the field update only allow you to update one field. In my case I'm trying to update mulitple fields at once.

Comment: You can associate multiple field updates with a single workflow. You just need to repeat the step of adding field update action.